# Adding next and prev buttons using react.js

Tags: reactjs, pagination

**I succeded to paginate my posts but couldn't add next and prev buttons and make them dynamically using this code snippet:**

```
import React from 'react'

const Pagination = ({postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate}) => {
    console.log(totalPosts)
    const PageNumbers = []

    const int = Math.ceil(totalPosts / postsPerPage)
    if (int === 1 ) return null 
    for (let i = 1; i<= int; i++) {
        PageNumbers.push(i) 
    }
    return (
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul className="pagination">
                {PageNumbers.map(number=> (
                    <li key={number} className="page-item">
                        <a onClick={ ()=> paginate(number)} href="!#" className="page-link">
                            {number} 
                        </a>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
export default Pagination
```

**please help to find way to include these buttons next and prev dynamically to my pagination who appears down. It's working great but needs next and prev**

[image]

Comment: You have to maintain some notion of your current page. Do you have a way to figure out your current page?

Comment: take a look at: https://github.com/titanve/react-next-paging/blob/master/src/react-next-paging.js

Answer (score 3):

Let's give your component some state so it can know the current page and, therefore, can know how to go to the next page. This should get you pretty close!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Pagination = ({postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate}) => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0)

    console.log(totalPosts)
    const PageNumbers = []

    const int = Math.ceil(totalPosts / postsPerPage)
    if (int === 1 ) return null 
    for (let i = 1; i<= int; i++) {
        PageNumbers.push(i) 
    }
    return (
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul className="pagination">
                {PageNumbers.includes(currentPage - 1) && <a onClick={() => {
                    setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
                    paginate(currentPage - 1);
                }}>}
                    Prev
                </a>
                {PageNumbers.map(number=> (
                    <li key={number} className="page-item">
                        <a onClick={()=> {
                            setCurrentPage(number)
                            paginate(number)
                        }} href="!#" className="page-link">
                            {number} 
                        </a>
                    </li>
                ))}
                {PageNumbers.includes(currentPage + 1) && <a onClick={() => {
                    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
                    paginate(currentPage + 1);
                }}>}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
export default Pagination
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

const getPrevious  = () => {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)
    }
    const getNext  = () => {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
    }
```

and need to use these functions on previous and next buttons. This worked for me fortunately

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Pagination = ({ postPerPage, totalPosts, paginate, }) => {
const [index, setIndex] = useState(1);
const pageNumbers = [];
for (let index = 1; index <= Math.ceil(totalPosts /postPerPage);index++) 
{
    pageNumbers.push(index);
}

return (
    <nav className='your-custom-styles'>
        <ul className="your-custom-styles">
            <li>
                <Link
                    onClick={() => {
                        if (pageNumbers.includes(index - 1)) {
                            setIndex(index - 1);
                            paginate(index - 1);
                        }
                    }}
                    className="your-custom-styles">
                    Previous
                </Link>
            </li>
            {pageNumbers.map((number) =>
                <li key={number}>
                    <Link onClick={() => 
                       {
                         setIndex(number);
                         paginate(number); 
                       }} 
                     className="your-custom-styles">{number}</Link>
                </li>
            )}
            <li>
                <Link
                    onClick={() => {
                        if (pageNumbers.includes(index + 1)) {
                            console.log(index)
                            setIndex(index + 1);
                            paginate(index + 1);
                        }
                    }}
                    className="your-custom-styles">
                    Next
                </Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
);}

 export default Pagination;
```